# What are the best client feedback tools around?

Tags: website-design

What are the best client feedback tools around, for getting the clients feedback on designs, wireframes, workflows and even the final product?

I have found a few that do just the design, but none that really do the whole project.  ideally I am looking for something that the client logs in to, can add feedback and then we login and fix, or respond to feedback.

I want to replace the 100 emails I get that dribble through with one bit of feedback at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like using Zurb's Notable for this. They even have desktop and iOS utility apps that tie in.

http://notableapp.com